# Mysterious stack overflow in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, stack-overflow, c++builder, c++builder-6

This is class hierarchy that my program uses:

[image]

The constructor of TForm_Upgrade_Database is looking like following:

__fastcall TForm_Upgrade_Database::TForm_Upgrade_Database(TComponent* Owner, 
    int newest_version)
        : TForm(Owner)
    {
    }

After trying to create instance of formular

```
TForm_Upgrade_Database *dlg = new TForm_Upgrade_Database(this, newest_version);
```

my program throws EStackOverflow exception

[image]

I stopped program and ran it again with breakpoint in TForm_Upgrade_Database constructor. After few steps callstack looks like this:

[image]

How is it that TCustomForm constructor keeps trying to call constructor of its descendant???

**Minimal test case:**

so_project.cpp:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "f_form.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
   TForm_Upgrade_Database *form = new TForm_Upgrade_Database(NULL, 10);
   delete form;
   form = NULL; 

   return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

f_form.cpp:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "f_form.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm_Upgrade_Database *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm_Upgrade_Database::TForm_Upgrade_Database(TComponent* Owner, int x)
   : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

f_form.h:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef f_formH
#define f_formH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm_Upgrade_Database : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
   __fastcall TForm_Upgrade_Database(TComponent* Owner, int x);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm_Upgrade_Database *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Comment: Screenshots and diagrams don't really help anyone in identifying the problem.  Please construct a [**minimal** test case](http://sscce.org), and then post the code.

Comment: are you creating another update object in the constructor?

Comment: Another Stack Overflow problem on StackOverflow :)

Comment: TForm and other classes that follow are part of vcl library, i don't know what are they doing.

Comment: post a small complete program that illustrates the problem

Comment: The problem seems to be in the TCustomForm constructor, one of its member variables, or one of their constructors.

Comment: Added minimal test case.

Comment: can you post the code the `TForm` as well?, especially the `TForm_Upgrade_Dtabase` and `Check_Database_Version` functions? Also `TCustomForm`...

Comment: @truthseeker: try to reverse the order of parameters for your constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TForm` has a virtual construtor that takes `TComponent*` and `int` parameters, in that order.  You are overriding that constructor.  By calling the base-class constructor that only takes a `TComponent*` parameter, you are in fact creating a recursive loop when those constructors call each other internally.

The solution is what truthseeker said.  You have to change the parameters of your derived constructor so you are not overriding the base class `TComponent*/int` constructor anymore.  Changing the order of the parameters is enough, or you can change the `int` to a different data type.

Comment: Good catch. I've never hit this problem, but that's more by luck than judgement...

Comment: Interesting, I didn't noticed this. I have just tried every way possible to get it run.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with some non-standard solutions in delphi library. VCL libraries are written and compiled in Delphi Pascal. Cooperation with C++ is made through interface files (with extension *.hpp). Compiled binary code is probably searching for constructor parameters on incorrect memory offsets. So this is probably a problem of calling convention.

I succeeded creating instance of formular when changing parameters in constructor so that the new parameter is first.

f_form.h:

```
__fastcall TForm_Upgrade_Database(int x, TComponent* Owner);
```

f_form.cpp:

```
__fastcall TForm_Upgrade_Database::TForm_Upgrade_Database(int x, TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
```

so_project.cpp:

```
TForm_Upgrade_Database *form = new TForm_Upgrade_Database(10, NULL);
```